# Connect 4 java win check

Tags: java

I've tried looking uo ways to do a win check bad sadly I'm having a hard time understanding it, I managed to try and get some code down but it doesn't work for some reason. It won't print out the statement and I'm not sure how I can return the winner in the winner method I'm also lost on diagonal search

Ive tried doing a vertical check first by doing the for loop starting at I then another loop for j which will start at columns then rows and another one starting at J and I which checks for horizontal I am completely lost on Diagonal search.

```
public class Connect4 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // DON'T MODIFY THE MAIN METHOD UNLESS FOR DEBUGGING
       //MAKE SURE YOU GET RID OF YOUR MODIFICATIONS HERE BEFORE 
SUBMISSION

       String[][] board = createEmptyBoard();
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       boolean bl = true;

       printPattern(board);

       while(bl) {        
           int player1 = 1 , player2 = 2 ,  userInput;
           System.out.println("Please drop a RED disk at the column between 0 and 6:");
           userInput = input.nextInt();
           dropDisk(board, userInput , player1);
           printPattern(board);

           System.out.println("Please drop a YELLOW disk at the column between 0 and 6:");
           userInput  = input.nextInt();
           dropDisk(board, userInput , player2);
           printPattern(board);            

           String win = checkWinner(board);
           /* Write code to announce  if there is  winner and end the game */
       } 
   }

   public static String[][] createEmptyBoard() {
       /* This method prints the first empty pattern for the game DON'T MODIFY THIS METHOD */
       String[][] f = new String[7][15];
       for (int i =0;i<f.length;i++) {
           for (int j =0;j<f[i].length;j++) {
               if (j% 2 == 0) f[i][j] ="|";
               else f[i][j] = " ";

               if (i==6) f[i][j]= "-";
           }
       }
       return f;
   } // end of createEmptyBoard 

   public static void printPattern(String[][] brd) {
       for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
           System.out.println(brd[i][0] + brd[i][1]+ brd[i][2]+ brd[i][3]+ brd[i][4]+ brd[i][5]+ brd[i][6]+ brd[i][7]+ brd[i][8]+ brd[i]     [9]+brd[i][10]+ brd[i][11]+ brd[i][12]+ brd[i][13]+ brd[i][14]);
       }
   } // end of printPattern

   public static String dropDisk(String[][] brd, int position, int player) {
       if(position < 0 || position > 6){
           return null;
       }
       String disk = player == 1 ? "R" : "Y";

       int col = 2 * position + 1;
       // start looking for a free slot at the very bottom

       int row = 5;

       while (row >= 0 && !brd[row][col].equals(" ")) {
           // move one row up
           row--;
       }

       // free slot found, disk can be placed
       if (row >= 0) {
           brd[row][col] = disk;        
           return disk;        
       }

       return null;
   } // end of dropDisk

   public static void checkWinner(String[][] brd) {      
       for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
           int count = 0;
           for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++){
              if(brd[i][j].equals("R")){
                 count++;
              }
              else {
                 count = 0;
              }

              if (count >= 4){
                  System.out.println("R is the winner");
                  //horizontal check
              }
          }        
       }

       for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
           int count = 0;
           for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
               if(brd[j][i].equals("R")){
                   count++;
               }
               else{
                   count = 0;
               }

               if(count >= 4){
                   System.out.println("The winner is R");
                   //Verticle check
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be easier to follow your code (for you as well as us) if you were consistent in your win check's variable naming: `i` vs `R` and `j` vs `C`.

Comment: And I don't think you mean `count += count + 1;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Will do let me edit that

Comment: @Nhami I've edited my answer once more, see if it helps now :)

Comment: @RoboMop Wow honestly thanks that makes much more sense, im a little new to arrays and have little knowledge on it this helps a lot im still a little lost but im gonna try it on pen and paper soon thanks a lot for your time appreciate it a lot (Im new to this platform how can I give you a thumbs up because my upvotes don't show up)

Comment: @Nhami Don't mention it :) As for the whole upvotes thing, I guess you need at least 15 reputation to do so, but don't worry about it

Comment: @RoboMop Thanks really appreciate it im gonna try it out myself eventually but for now I will try and read the code thanks for your time btw just tried to implement it in my program you know why I get an out of bound statement is it for my previous code for the horizontal and veriticle check?

Comment: @RoboMop seems that somehow my code is going out of bounce due to the array spot im unsure how to fix this could you help explain

Comment: @Nhami Sure, I'll take another look at it. Could you also mention which line is giving the error?

Comment: @RoboMop I am unsure where but after I input "Y" in row 1 "Please drop a YELLOW disk at the column 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
---------------
 at connect4.Connect4.checkWinner(Connect4.java:189)
 at connect4.Connect4.main(Connect4.java:43)
/Users/stevenguyen/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 5 seconds)"

Comment: @Nhami I've got the problem, I seem to have used `j++` in the second block of text, whereas it should be `j--`. I've edited the answer now, it should work fine!

Comment: @Nhami Does the code work now?

Comment: @RoboMop yeah but the print statements aren't running for some odd reason

Comment: @Nhami What do you mean by `print statements aren't running`? Can you maybe edit your question with the input you are using?

Comment: @RoboMop sorry I meant to say that it won't count 4 disks so if I entered 4 disks diagonally it won't read it and print out the winner

Comment: @Nhami It seems that I forgot to take the `|` into consideration. I'll be editing my answer with the (hopefully) final version in a while

Comment: @RoboMop thanks appreciate it will look forward to it

Comment: @Nhami I've submitted an another answer which will run perfectly (mostly) for your assignment. I've changed the diagonal parts to exclude the pipes `|` and the underscores `_`, and the return type of `checkWin()`. I don't think I'll be able to explain everything again, but if you've understood my previous answer, I'm sure you won't have any problem deciphering this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Connect4 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DON'T MODIFY THE MAIN METHOD UNLESS FOR DEBUGGING
        //MAKE SURE YOU GET RID OF YOUR MODIFICATIONS HERE BEFORE 

        String[][] board = createEmptyBoard();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean bl = true;

        printPattern(board);

        while(bl) {        
            int player1 = 1 , player2 = 2 ,  userInput;
            System.out.println("Please drop a RED disk at the column between 0 and 6:");
            userInput = input.nextInt();
            dropDisk(board, userInput , player1);
            printPattern(board);

            String win = checkWinner(board);
            if(!win.equals(""))
            {
                System.out.println(win+" is the winner!");
                break;
            }

            System.out.println("Please drop a YELLOW disk at the column between 0 and 6:");
            userInput  = input.nextInt();
            dropDisk(board, userInput , player2);
            printPattern(board);

            win = checkWinner(board);
            if(!win.equals(""))
            {
                System.out.println(win+" is the winner!");
                break;
            }
            /* Write code to announce  if there is  winner and end the game */
        } 
    }

    public static String[][] createEmptyBoard() {
        /* This method prints the first empty pattern for the game DON'T MODIFY THIS METHOD */
        String[][] f = new String[7][15];
        for (int i =0;i<f.length;i++) {
            for (int j =0;j<f[i].length;j++) {
                if (j% 2 == 0) f[i][j] ="|";
                else f[i][j] = " ";

                if (i==6) f[i][j]= "-";
            }
        }
        return f;
    } // end of createEmptyBoard 

    public static void printPattern(String[][] brd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            System.out.println(brd[i][0] + brd[i][1]+ brd[i][2]+ brd[i][3]+ brd[i][4]+ brd[i][5]+ brd[i][6]+ brd[i][7]+ brd[i][8]+ brd[i]     [9]+brd[i][10]+ brd[i][11]+ brd[i][12]+ brd[i][13]+ brd[i][14]);
        }
    } // end of printPattern

    public static String dropDisk(String[][] brd, int position, int player) {
        if(position < 0 || position > 6){
            return null;
        }
        String disk = player == 1 ? "R" : "Y";

        int col = 2 * position + 1;
        // start looking for a free slot at the very bottom

        int row = 5;

        while (row >= 0 && !brd[row][col].equals(" ")) {
            // move one row up
            row--;
        }

        // free slot found, disk can be placed
        if (row >= 0) {
            brd[row][col] = disk;        
            return disk;        
        }

        return null;
    } // end of dropDisk

    public static String checkWinner(String[][] brd) {      
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                if(brd[i][j].equals("R"))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else count = 0;

                if(count == 4)
                {
                    return "R";
                }
            }        
        }
        //Vertical Check for "Y"
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
            {
                if(brd[i][j].equals("Y"))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else count = 0;

                if(count == 4)
                {
                    return "Y";
                }
            }        
        }

        // Horizontal Check for "R"
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if(brd[j][i].equals("R"))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else count = 0;

                if(count == 4)
                {
                    return "R";
                }
            }        
        }
        // Horizontal Check for "Y"
        for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                if(brd[j][i].equals("Y"))
                {
                    count++;
                }
                else count = 0;

                if(count == 4)
                {
                    return "Y";
                }
            }        
        }

        // Check for a diagonal to the bottom and right
        for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j < brd[i].length-7; j = j + 2)
            {
                if(brd[i][j].equals("R"))
                {
                    if(brd[i+1][j+2].equals("R") && brd[i+2][j+4].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j+6].equals("R"))
                    {
                        return "R";
                    }
                }
                else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y"))
                {
                    if(brd[i+1][j+2].equals("Y") && brd[i+2][j+4].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j+6].equals("Y"))
                    {
                        return "Y";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Check for a diagonal to the bottom and left
        for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-4; i++)
        {
            for(int j = brd[i].length-2; j >= 7; j = j - 2)
            {
                if(brd[i][j].equals("R"))
                {
                    if(brd[i+1][j-2].equals("R") && brd[i+2][j-4].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j-6].equals("R"))
                    {
                        return "R";
                    }
                }
                else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y"))
                {
                    if(brd[i+1][j-2].equals("Y") && brd[i+2][j-4].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j-6].equals("Y"))
                    {
                        return "Y";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Here is the COMPLETE CLASS CODE, and I've stuck to the rules your project assignment was given. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this out:

```
// Check for a diagonal to the bottom and right
for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-3; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < brd[i].length-3; j++)
    {
        if(brd[i][j].equals("R"))
        {
            if(brd[i+1][j+1].equals("R") && brd[i+2][j+2].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j+3].equals("R"))
            {
                System.out.println("R is the winner!");
            }
        }
        else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y"))
        {
            if(brd[i+1][j+1].equals("Y") && brd[i+2][j+2].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j+3].equals("Y"))
            {
                System.out.println("Y is the winner!");
            }
        }
    }
}

// Check for a diagonal to the bottom and left
for(int i = 0; i < brd.length-3; i++)
{
    for(int j = brd.length-1; j >= 3; j--)
    {
        if(brd[i][j].equals("R"))
        {
            if(brd[i+1][j-1].equals("R") && brd[i+2][j-2].equals("R") && brd[i+3][j-3].equals("R"))
            {
                System.out.println("R is the winner!");
            }
        }
        else if(brd[i][j].equals("Y"))
        {
            if(brd[i+1][j-1].equals("Y") && brd[i+2][j-2].equals("Y") && brd[i+3][j-3].equals("Y"))
            {
                System.out.println("Y is the winner!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Explanation -

The first block deals with top-left to bottom-right diagonal. It checks each column until the 3rd from the right is reached, because a diagonal cannot exist after that.
It checks each row the same way until the 3rd from the bottom is reached, because a diagonal cannot exist after that.

If any of the above checked cells contains an `R`, you can then check the cells diagonally to the bottom right of that, by simply using `brd[i+1][j+1]`. Remember, you WON'T get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because we already made sure the checked cells are within the index limits.

**NOTE**- I used `brd[i+1][j+1]` so that we check the cell in the bottom row, and one column to the right.

The second block deals with top-right to bottom-left diagonal. It checks each row until the 3rd from the bottom is reached, because a diagonal cannot exist after that.

Now, it checks each column of the ROW, starting from the RIGHT to the LEFT, until the 3rd column from the left is reached. This is because no 4 element diagonal can exist after that (Try using a pen-and-paper drawing of a matrix, it
'll help you understand better).

If any of the above checked cells contains an `R`, you can then check the cells diagonally to the bottom right of that, by simply using `brd[i+1][j-1]`. Remember, you WON'T get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, because we already made sure the checked cells are within the index limits.

**NOTE**- I used `brd[i+1][j-1]` so that we check the cell in the bottom row, and one column to the left.

If you feel the explanation is too convoluted... well, it probably is. You'll understand much better by drawing a square with 7x15 tiles, and doing a test run of this program on paper :)

Comment: Will do @RoboMop could you explain It to me as well? Im fairly new to java and just picked this up not to long ago why do you subtract 3 from the length and also why do we add and subtract three from the array in your if statements